# Xcode's XIB and Storyboard's UIElements are not visible

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 11.5, sometime UIElements on XIB or Storyboard file are not visible. Only blue placeholder rectangles are visible. If clean the project, delete derived data, quit and reopen the project it works but sometime not. I faced same issue in older Xcode version also. Any solution?

[image]

Comment: Having sometimes the same issue, I usually quit Xcode and restart it to have the UI displayed again. It looks like a plain old bug to me... ‍♂️

Comment: I am doing same thing right now but some time need to quit and open multiple time that is frustrating and time wastage. Some time if close storyboard/xib tab it also works. 
May be someone have better solution.